# Fast searching an Outlook Address list

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, addressbook

I want to search an huge address list from outlook for an AddressEntry by the email address. Searching by name is not problem, as you can write:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry = AddressEntries[Name];
```

But I want to find the Entry by its email. This code is working but extremely slow:

```
    public static string GetUserDataByEmailAddress(string EmailAddress)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OLApp = null;
        bool OutlookWasRunning = false;
        string UserName = string.Empty;

        if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
        {
            OLApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
            OutlookWasRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OLApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = OLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            nameSpace.Logon("", "", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            nameSpace = null;
            OutlookWasRunning = false;
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressLists GALs = null;
        GALs = OLApp.Session.AddressLists;
        if (GALs == null) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Unable to get address book collection from MS Outlook!"); }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressList gal = null;
        gal = GALs["Globale Adressliste"];
        if (gal == null) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Unable to get address book 'Global Address List' from MS Outlook!"); }

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry ent in gal.AddressEntries)
        {
            if(ent.Address == EmailAddress) { UserName = ent.Name; }
        }

        if (!OutlookWasRunning) { OLApp.Quit(); }

        return UserName;
    }
```

Ok, but this way works very slow. Now, I tried to use the AddressEntries as an IEnumeratable to do this:

```
var output = from a in gal.AddressEntries.AsQueryable() where (a as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry).Address == EmailAddress select a;
```

Doing that, I get the error:

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS1936  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'IQueryable'.  'Where' not found.`

Does anybody know an fast way to search for the correct AddressEntry?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not loop through all items in a container - some containers can contain tens of thousands of entries or more.

You can use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` in OOM - that will resolve a name (or address) against all containers. This is equivalent to typing a name in the To edit box in Outlook and hitting Ctrl+K.

If you want to resolve against a particular container (e.g. "All Users" GAL container), you would need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only). You can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language) - it exposes [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).[AddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).`ResolveName` / `ResolveNameEx` and [RDOAddresList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).`ResolveName` / `ResolveNameEx` .

Keep in mind that resolving against a particular container (`PR_ANR` resolution in MAPI) might not work if using an SMTP address (GAL limitation).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this container contains over 400.000 people and there seems to be a slow connection to the exchange server. Even if I use `AddressList.AddressEntries.Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry>().ToList()` takes a very long time.